# To study & analyse vulnerability on Pdf

Tags: security, pdf, malware, malware-detection

This is my project topic given by my college. Can somebody please give me an idea on where to start with this topic.

I have seen a lot of topics on pdf vulnerability but the problem is they require knowing a lot of security stuff beforehand. I have less than a week to submit the project. 
If somebody could just guide me to where I should start I would be really grateful. 
I have already looked up didier stievens site but its getting really tough for me to understand it since there is no time.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You may be asking on the wrong site. Maybe you should ask on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One exploit with pdf is to package your own code within the file. This links shows how to do this. http://securityxploded.com/pdf_vuln_exploits.php

Answer (score 1):

The most important point about PDF security is that most 'popular' attacks are targeting:

- application related vulnerabilities in most popular free PDF reading applications: [Adobe Reader](https://acrobat.adobe.com/) and [Foxit Reader](http://foxitsoftware.com/);
- humans to get them to click on the malicious attachment inside PDF to initiate attack;

Check these analysis and parsing utilities and documents:

- [Didier Stevens's pdf tools](http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/) which include `make-pdf-javascript.py` (  javascript injection tool), `pdfid.py` that scans PDF and embedded javascripts for keywords and others;
- [PDF Stream Dumper](http://sandsprite.com/blogs/index.php?uid=7&pid=57) and its [source code](https://github.com/dzzie/pdfstreamdumper);
- [PDF Miner Py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k) - pdf parsing library made with python;
- [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) - javascript based PDF rendering that could help you to learn PDF structure parsing right from your browser console (widely used in lot of online services like [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/))
- Official PDF Format Specification from Adobe for [PDF 1.4](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf) and [PDF 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)